# Activating the GPS on QField for Windows Desktop (beta)

Tags: qgis, gps, qfield, windows-10, tablet

Has anyone figured out how to activate the GPS on the computer to use in QField-Windows?

I have a Getac field tablet/computer.
I've created a QGIS Project with 3 vector layers and packaged for QField.
I've successfully tested my computer GPS with QGIS-GPS Tools, and other software.
And I've tested the QField project on my Android phone with no issues.

I'm using QField for Windows (beta --> https://qfield.org/docs/install/)

Comment: it's beta software it is not implemented yet on windows https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/2038 - you will see "serialnmea: No known GPS device found. Specify the COM port via QT_NMEA_SERIAL_PORT" in cmd prompt running qfield (windows)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Qfield for Windows 2.0.14 beta with an Altus Cpos GPS, connected via Bluetooth. It was easily discovered after Qfield did a scan, then simply selecting from a list. Bear in mind, this was not on the same tablet you have. But all i did on my tablet was to make sure Bluetooth was on. All the connection work from a user-perspective seems to be handled rather well by Qfield.

However, I had some challenges connecting over time (not always succesful, or not always performing ok).

Answer (score 0):

With the latest download (v. 2.6.2, available here: https://docs.qfield.org/get-started/#__tabbed_1_3) it is possible.  I have a EOS GNSS Arrow 100 (https://eos-gnss.com/products/hardware/arrow-100).  Connect to the receiver by bluetooth normally through windows control panel. Then in the EOS tools software, I had to active a virtual COM port.  Then in Qfield, under the POSITIONING tab in settings, I was able to set up the virtual COM port. Each type of receiver likely has a slightly different procedure and software for activating the virtual COM port.